# I want to write the XQuery to print the specific keys in JSON and want to except if it has an array value

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10

I want to write the XQuery to print the specific keys in JSON and want to except if it has an array value.

Sample JSON:

```
{
  "id":"743",
  "transation":{
    "101":"success",
    "102":"rejected",
    "301":"processing"
   },
  "groupName":"group1"
}
```

Expected Result:

```
id

groupName
```

Comment: You don't want to print the `transation` property. Just to clarify, it's an object - not an array. Is your requirement only to print if it's a simple property with an atomic value, and skip over objects AND arrays?

Comment: And are you reading the JSON as a document in the database?

Comment: Yes, reading JSON from the database, yes i need to skip objects and array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are reading a JSON document from the database, you could iterate over the object property nodes and filter out the object/array properties by testing whether the property has child nodes:

```
for $property in  doc("/test.json")/object-node()/node()
where not($property/node())
return $property/name()
```

Or you could exclude those that are `instance of` `object-node()` or `array-node()`

```
for $property in  doc("/test.json")/object-node()/node()
where not($property instance of object-node() or $property instance of array-node())
return $property/name()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if marklogic follows the W3C spec here, but in XQuery 3.1 you can do

```
let $json := json-doc('my.json') 
return map:keys($json)[not($json(.) instance of array(*))]
```